# Eclipse keeps removing my .so libraries when the Android App Launches

Tags: android, eclipse

I don't know what change I have made recently, and I am trying to figure it out.  This morning, when I launch one of my Android applications that I am developing on my device, it always removes the other .so files in the /armeabi /armeabi-v7a /x86 folders.  It didn't used to remove the .so files there upon launch.  Not sure what kind of configuration changed to make in order to return it to a working state.

Has anyone else come across this before while developing in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the issue had been with the .cproject file.  At some point this had gotten changed by the environment.  When I deleted the .cproject file, it went back to behaving as normal.  Leaving the .so files in the application as they are upon launch of the application.

Now, this is probably just a means to work around what in the .cproject file was causing this issue.  However, since the local .so files of the application only needed an update once and don't need to be recompiled every time, this works just fine.  The libraries are made, I can delete the .cproject file and then include the other .so library files from other libraries just fine and continue with normal operation.

If someone else comes up with what could have been done as part of a property in the .cproject file then that could aide others who run into this issue in the future.

Comment: you probably could help along by posting the current content of the file so it could be analyzed

Comment: @DigCamara Apologies.  It has already gone through deletion and a check-in at this point.  Trying to push forward on the project at the moment and don't have it readily available without doing some back-pedaling.